# python builder design patter unresolved reference error

Tags: python, return, builder, setter, self

```
class AlgDispenser:

    # super class to output an algorithm out of a selection of algorithms
    def __init__(self, *algorithms: Algorithm):
        super().__init__()
        self._algs: list[Algorithm] = []
        self._activeAlg: int = 0
        for i in range(0, len(algorithms)):
            self._algs.append(algorithms[i])
            
    def addAlgorithm(self, alg: Algorithm) ->AlgDispenser:
        # builder pattern
        self._algs.append(alg)
        return  self
```

->AlgDispenser: shows me an unresolved err for some reason

Comment: Wrap it in single quotes `''`

Comment: `-> 'AlgDispenser'`

Comment: the fix is to add this line at code line 1:
from __future__ import annotations